# how can i multibind rect in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

hello I've tried to multibind of rectangle.
but i've got `System.InvalidCastException: ‘Unable to cast object of type ‘MS.Internal.NamedObject’ to type ‘System.Boolean’.’ error`

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{

        SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

        if (values == null)
        {
            return color;
        }
        bool A= (bool)(values[0]);
        bool B= (bool)values[1];

        if (A&& B)
        {
            color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

        else if (A== true && B== false)
        {
            color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

        }
        else if (A== true && B== true)
        {
            color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
        
        else
        {
            color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
        }
        return color;

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I Want to change colors of rectangle depending on conditions.

`xaml`

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BackGroundColorConverters}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckAStatus"/>
                        <Binding Path="CheckDStatus"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
```

> private bool _checkAStatus;
> public bool CheckAStatus
> {
> get => _checkAStatus;
> set => SetProperty(ref _checkAStatus, value);
>
> ```
> }
> ```
>
> private bool _checkDStatus;
> public bool CheckDStatus
> {
> get => _checkDStatus;
> set => SetProperty(ref _checkDStatus, value);
> }
> public ViewModel()
> {
> this.CheckAstatus = false;
> this.CheckDstats = true;
> }

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: I wonder how the converter can get anything that isn't a bool from those bool properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should validate the arguments in your `Convert` method and do nothing when an `MS.Internal.NamedObject` is passed as an argument:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (values == null || values.Length < 2 || !(values[0] is bool A) || !(values[1] is bool B)
        return Binding.DoNothing;

    SolidColorBrush color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);

    if (values == null)
    {
        return color;
    }

    if (A && B)
    {
        color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    else if (A == true && B == false)
    {
        color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);

    }
    else if (A == true && B == true)
    {
        color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }

    else
    {
        color = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightBlue);
    }
    return color;
}
```